# SQL "like query" on varchar column in H2 not using index

Tags: java, indexing, h2

In our application using a H2 database (version 1.4.196) we have a search on a varchar field doing either "contains" (`column like '%searchterm%`) or "begins with" (`column like 'searchterm%`) searches.

The table is quite large (approx. 400,000 entries) and the search turns out to be slow (varying between 3 seconds on my local development computer to 6 to 12 seconds on our customer's machines).

I found out that the column in question was not indexed and added an index. It turned out that the search time did not improve, even when I added an index hint explicitly to the query. `explain` revealed to me that no index was used in both cases.

From my experience with other database systems (e.g. MSSQL) I know that, at least for "begins with" queries, indexes can be used to improve search peformances.

As I did not find any related documentation for the H2 database my question:

**Is it possible to use indexes in `like` queries in H2?**

Comment: H2 can't use an index for either of those conditions (and neither could SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Most DB systems WILL use the index if you have a LIKE query... but only up to the first % in it. There is pretty much no DB system in existence where the mere act of having an index on the column would have any effect on the speed of, say: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE '%findme%';`.

What you are presumably looking for is an index specifically designed to aid in searching. For example, the **tsquery** system that postgres has (see [postgres tsquery documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-tables.html)).

Another way to go is to add a dependency to your software that does this. The obvious choice there is [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/).

H2 has some support for this. Please refer to [H2 documentation on full text search](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#fulltext).

Comment: I'm aware of the limitation to work until the first % (which I stated in the question). I think the full text search was activated once in the project but was deactived later **for reasons**. I guess I'll have a look at it. Thanks.